# Comparing stacks based on the elements in them ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, stack

So I'm learning ruby and I was learning about mixins today and decided to implement a comparison method for my stack class. I was comparing stacks based on their size first but I wanted to include the functionality whereby if the stack sizes were equal then I would compare each element within the stacks to determine which one was bigger. And if all the elements were equal, only then would the two stacks be equal. Here's my code:

```
class Stack
   include Enumerable
   include Comparable

attr: stack

def initialize 
  @stack = []
end

def pop(element) 
      @stack.push(element)
end


def push(element) 
      @stack.pop(element)
end

def <=>(other)
      if stack.size == other.stack.size then
         stack.zip(other.stack).all? { |s, other| s <=> other}
      else
         stack.size <=> other.stack.size
      end
end
end
```

But this fails for when I have the following test:

```
s1 = Stack.new
s2 = Stack.new

s1.push(1)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(3)

s2.push(1)
s2.push(2)
s2.push(4)

s2 > s1 # Should be true but is false
```

Comment: What does your `Stack` class really look like? What you have there is not syntactically valid. Also, why is `Stack#pop` implemented using `Array#push` and `Stack#push` implemented using `Array#pop`? Furthermore, `<=>` returns a `Fixnum` (-1, 0, +1) but `any?` expects its block to return true or false so `all? { |s, other| s <=> other}` doesn't do anything useful as you're effectively saying `all? { true }`. I think it is time to learn some debugging skills.

Comment: how are you suppose to handle the case where `s1` has a few values greater than `s2`, and `s2` has a few values greater than `s1`?

Comment: @muistooshort Apart from indentation and a missing end for the class I don't see how this is not syntactically valid. That's literally what it looks like. It runs without errors on my machine. Also I was creating my very own array backed stack class. Does it matter how I did it? If I knew how to do the last part, I wouldn't ask here. I don't know how to compare elements in two arrays and return the one that has bigger elements. Can't debug if I don't even know how to approach the solution can I? I have looked around. Didn't find anything useful for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @davidhu2000 True. Didn't think about that. Let's just say there will only be one element bigger than the other when comparing the two arrays if their sizes are equal. I don't want to make this little exercise more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: `attr: stack` and `attr :stack` are very different things. Read the docs on [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-push),  [`Array#pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-pop), [`Object#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), and [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to see where you're going wrong. Some things have to be learned the hard way.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did to make this work. There's definitely better ways, but this is functional.

```
class Stack
  include Enumerable
  include Comparable

    attr :stack

    def initialize 
      @stack = []
    end

    def pop(element) 
      @stack.pop(element)
    end

    def push(element) 
      @stack.push(element)
    end

    def <=>(other)
      if stack.size == other.stack.size then
         stack.zip(other.stack).each do |s, other|
           return s <=> other unless other == s 
         end
         return 0
      else
         stack.size <=> other.stack.size
      end
    end

    def >(other)
        (self <=> other) == 1
    end

    def <(other)
        (self <=> other) == -1 
    end

    def ==(other)
        (self <=> other) == 0 
    end
end
```

So what I did is have the `<=>` method return either `-1`, `0`, or `1`. Based on your example, if the size of `s2` is greater than `s1`, then the function will return `1`. And if `s2` has one value greater than `s1`, then it will also return `1`.

I also defined the `>`, `<`, and `==` methods that checks the value returned from the `<=>` method to determine whether to output `true` or `false` on the comparison.

```
s1 = Stack.new
s2 = Stack.new

s1.push(1)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(3)

s2.push(1)
s2.push(2)
s2.push(4)

s2 > s1 #=> true
```

This corrects your issue, and the comparison above returns `true`.

Comment: Don't define `>` , `>` and `==`; you get those (and others) for free when you `include Comparable` . Do however define an `each` method when you `include Enumerable` .